# How to add custom indentation rules to align multiple lines of code when creating a language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm authoring an extension for Racket (lisp dialect) and I'd like to customize the indentation rules further than just "when line ends with X, indentation +1, else indentation -1". However, as far as I understand it, that exactly is the point of `increaseIndentPattern` and `decreaseIndentPattern` in `language-configuration.json`.

In particular, I'd like to specify some rule that goes like this:

```lisp
(call-foo first-arg
......... second-arg
......... (third-arg-function foo
..............................bar))
```

Where the dots denote the auto-indentation (spaces) automatically inserted by VS Code upon pressing `return` on the preceeding lines. Is it possible to do something like this?